# Auth and user service decouple - expressjs

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

im creating a mobile application and couldn't really find a proper way to try and decouple these 2 services:

1. Auth Service - Issues JWT tokens, handles refresh token and sign in / out etc.
2. User Service - Handles the creation of users, user info, roles etc.

Both services has its own database + there is also an API gateway in front of these services that verifies their jwt token.

The scenario: A user registers for an account -> The user gets created and JWT + refresh token stored in each services DB and issued out to them.

Are there a proper standard solution to handle this scenario?

i'd prefer to not combine the auth and user service if possible.

Comment: why does your auth service have an DB? what do you save on it=

Comment: @Ifaruki i think they mean to store sessions in db?

Comment: @AmitParameshwar if he stores session, why does he use JWT? Thats not the purpose of JWT

Comment: @Ifaruki Sorry I meant `refresh-token`. Most probably they are storing that

Comment: Hey @Ifaruki, thanks! correct! its used to store some auth meta data such as refresh token, client id, secret etc, so itll purely be an auth service

Comment: @Ifaruki @ AmitParameshwar thinking of adding a webhook after auth -> webhook sends user data to (via signup) to user service, what do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

I kinda solved this by implementing a callback/hook to create the user after creating auth for the user - still not sure if its standard practice though....